# Acoustic echo cancelation windows xp/vista/7

Tags: c++, windows, acoustics

What is the preferred way to perform aec computation on windows xp/vista/7 using C++ ?

Is there an API that could deliver synchronized input and output samples so I could pass them to an external library like speex ?

Or maybe this embedded API itself perform the aec computation returning only the result so I can encode and transmit it to the remote site.

Is there any differences in aec support for xp/vista/7 ?

What is the best external library ( free or not ) for aec computation ? ( in this case I would need the input / output samples to be synchronized by the operating system )

Sample code would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an internet search for "AEC DMO".  It will turn up some useful MSDN links [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the AEC component shipped for Vista/Win7. There is a sample app for the DMO that shipped on Vista, but you may need to download the relevant Windows SDK to get at that code.

For XP, there's [IDirectSoundFullDuplexCreate8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directsoundfullduplexcreate8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Barely works on XP.  Doesn't work at all on Vista+.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know if it (Aec DMO - aka Voice capture DSP) works well on vista/7 ??

Comment: It's been a while. But I recall we shipped it as part of a well known VOIP/Video communication product around the time Vista shipped since we knew the existing AEC was toast.  YMMV.  The only subtle thing I recall it fails to work if you apply it to the recording stream without actually having the output device playing, which makes sense. It can't converge unless the other stream is actively going.

Comment: Another questions: 1) Is there any sample code on how to setup the xp aec ? 2) Do DirectSoundFullDuplexCreate8 and the Aec System filter ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536174(v=vs.85).aspx ) refer to the same thing or are they two separate aec mechanisms ?

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest looking at the AEC DMO sample that shipped with either the Windows Platform SDK for Vista or Win7. One of those downloads has the demo code.  For XP, you'll probably have to go way back and download a WinSDK from a long time ago.